# How can I fix my chat screen properly on flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a list of messages. But the messages don`t stay in the right place.
This is my code:

```
writeMessage(){
  db.doc(widget.guessId).collection('messages').add({
    'message': _message.text,
    'messageSender': user.currentUser!.uid,
    'createTime': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
 });
}
```

Retrieve messages:

```
  messages() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: db
          .doc(widget.guessId)
          .collection('messages')
          .orderBy('createTime', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const DottedCircularProgressIndicatorFb(
            currentDotColor: Colors.purple,
            defaultDotColor: Colors.blue,
            numDots: 6,
          );
        }
        List<Widget> messages = snapshot.data!.docs
            .map(
              (doc) => BubbleNormal(
                textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 15),
                text: doc['message'],
                color: const Color(0xffebebeb),
                isSender: user.currentUser!.uid == doc['messageSender']
                    ? true
                    : false,
                sent: true,
              ),
            )
            .toList();
        return ListView(
          reverse: true,
          children: messages,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Or Listview.Builder also same situation. messages do not stay sequentially

This is a photo example

[image: Photo]

Comment: Please, show more code like how do you write the message.

Comment: Sure, I was editing my question. I want to show messages sequentially. For example, I wrote a message on the right side, and you wrote message on the left side after I wrote a message again on the right side. Like a normal messaging chatting app style

Comment: If you look in `messages` collection directly, do you have the correct order of messages based on `createTime`?

Comment: I am writing `createTime` with `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch` .  and everything goes normal. But messages showing like the above picture

Comment: it should look like this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/content/images/2021/01/2021-01-20-13.52.45.gif